# PowerPoint: VBA Subscript out of range when looping array

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to use a loop to split a 1d array into a 2d array and populate text boxes in VBA. I get the error, subscript out of range for Table(j, i - 4) in the line that says: 
Table(j, i - 4) = inputArray(10 * (i - 4 - 1) + (j - 1))
Please let me know if there is a better way to do this, any help is appreciated

Part of the code is below

```
For i = 5 to 9 

Dim inputArray As Variant
Dim Table As Variant

inputArray = Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9)

For j = 1 To UBound(inputArray)
    Table = Array(j, i - 4)
    Table(j, i - 4) = inputArray(10 * (i - 4 - 1) + (j - 1))
Next j

Set oPicture = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=TBLeft1, Top:=TBTop1, _
        Width:=TBWidth1, Height:=TBHeight1)
    oPicture.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Table(1, (i - 4))
    With oPicture
    .ZOrder msoBringInFrontOfText
    End With
Set oPicture = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=TBLeft2, Top:=TBTop2, _
        Width:=TBWidth2, Height:=TBHeight2)
    oPicture.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Table(2, (i - 4))
    With oPicture
    .ZOrder msoBringInFrontOfText
    End With

Next i
```

Comment: What are you expecting `Table = Array(j, i - 4)` to do? I speculate you want to define a 2D array of dimensions j and i-4, but you are creating an array with two value, j and i-4. I think you wanted to use `ReDim`.

Comment: See [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/array-function) and [ReDim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/redim-statement)

Comment: Yes I would like to define a 2D array of dimensions j and i-4. How would I use ReDim to do that?    ReDim Table (j, i-4) ?

Comment: Change Table definition to `Dim Table() as Variant` to make it a dynamic array, then use `Redim Table(j, i-4)` to resize it as required.

Answer (score 0):

`Table` is a single dimensional array:

[image]

On this line `Table(j, i - 4)`, you are using it, as if it is a multidimensional one.

Try something as small as this one to get the meaning:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 5 To 9

        Dim inputArray As Variant
        Dim Table As Variant

        inputArray = Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)

        For j = 0 To 1
            Table = Array(j, i - 4)
            Table(j) = inputArray(i - 4)
            Debug.Print Table(j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```